# PyCharm Debug configuration for Scrapy spider raises error

Tags: python, intellij-idea, scrapy, pycharm

I want to `debug` a `scrapy` spider and I would like to use a `PyCharm debugger`.

The problem is that when I setup configuration and run debug, it raises:

```
Connected to pydev debugger (build 201.7846.77)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/milano/.virtualenvs/pamamasales/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 166, in <module>
    execute()
  File "/home/milano/.virtualenvs/pamamasales/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 112, in execute
    settings = get_project_settings()
  File "/home/milano/.virtualenvs/pamamasales/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/utils/project.py", line 69, in get_project_settings
    settings.setmodule(settings_module_path, priority='project')
  File "/home/milano/.virtualenvs/pamamasales/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/settings/__init__.py", line 287, in setmodule
    module = import_module(module)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'corespider.settings'
```

[image]

I also tried other working directories but everything raises this error.
Do you know what is wrong?

Comment: On a first look there is no error in PyCharm configuration (it should work as You expected). According to error log - application is unable to reach/load module called `corespider.settings` which defined in your project settings. Can you post your project settings?(at least that part where `corespider.settings` mentioned). Did you try to run application from the same python environment using scrapy command line tool?